# Use HTTP/2 together with PHP SQLSRV extensions?

Tags: linux, php, debian, apache-2.4, sql-server

I have a web site (Apache/2.4.46, HTTPS) using PHP7.3, MariaDb 10.4, MSSQL for Linux (mcr.microsoft.com/mssql/server:2019-latest), running on a Debian 10 server.

My setup works perfectly using HTTP/1.1.
However, I wanted to try HTTP/2 to see if I could speed up the site.

This did not work at all, the site just stopped responding. After a bit of research, i think I found at least a part of the problem:
The Apache2 + HTTP/1.1 configuration is standard, `a2enmod php7.3` and `a2enmod mpm_prefork`.
Changing to HTTP/2 requires disabling `php7.3, mpm_prefork` and switching to `mpm_event`. HTTP/2 is enabled in my virtual host section: `Protocols h2 http/1.1`.

This change stops all PHP SQLSRV extensions from working without any error messages. Looking at the non-responding site with Google Chrome Developer tools shows that HTTP/2 is in fact enabled and working, but all output stops after the first `sqlsrv_connect()` call.

RE-enabling php7.3 and mpm_prefork (i.e. back to HTTP/1.1) restores all functionality. Trying `a2enconf php7.3-fpm` in HTTP/2 mode does not help.

My question is if there is a way to use HTTP/2 and Apache together with PHP SQLSRV extensions on Linux?

Comment: IIRC using `mod_event` requires you to use PHP-FPM, and usually, `php.ini` locations for both SAPI (PHP-FPM/`mod_php`) is different. try using `phpinfo()` to check if both SAPI has `sqlsrv` module loaded.